# Sublime text 2 - change tags color

Tags: sublimetext2

I am using Sublime Text 2 - which i want to make it my default program for work.

I have install the Dreamweaver Theme - but i have some issues:

I dont know how to change the colors for tags (a, img, form, etc).
There are all in the same color, not like in Dreamweaver CS4 (see pic).

[image]

How can i change colors for each?

I have this in my theme code:

```
<dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>html img tag</string>
      <key>scope</key>
      <string>text.html meta.tag.img - string</string>
      <key>settings</key>
      <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#6d232eff</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
      <key>name</key>
      <string>html form tag</string>
      <key>scope</key>
      <string>text.html meta.tag.form - string</string>
      <key>settings</key>
      <dict>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#ff9700ff</string>
      </dict>
    </dict>
```

But when i change the colors in the string tag, not working - is there something missing?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tag name</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>entity.name.tag</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#EA0000</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Tag start/end</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>punctuation.definition.tag.html, punctuation.definition.tag.begin, punctuation.definition.tag.end</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#EA0000</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: Thank you! Was looking for this.

Answer (score 1):

It comes down to the language definition (`.tmLanguage`) file. By default the HTML language definition cuts off at the general tag level, don't ask me why, but it follows [TextMate's Scope Selector pattern](http://manual.macromates.com/en/scope_selectors). From what I can tell is people write the language file using JSON, and then convert it to a `.plist` file, and change the extension to a `tmLanguage` file.

The easiest thing I found was to [install Siddley's Enhanced HTML/ColdFusion package](https://github.com/Siddley/Enhanced.HTML.CFML), use the enhanced HTML language, and one of the DW color schemes.

> After some looking, I found that Siddley clumped some tags together. I may be extending the language definition file. Will post on github if I do.

Answer (score 1):

Follow this step to apply colour scheme of Dreamweaver cs5 in your sublime.

[Click here to download Dreamweaver Theme Zip File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xj9tjueqan1gnxc/SublimeDreamweaver-master.rar?dl=0)

**How to apply colour scheme like Dreamweaver CS5**

```
1. Download zip file from Dreamweaver Theme File Link
2. Extract folder
3. Open sublime and goto "Preferences">"Browser Packages..">"Paste extract folder here"
4. Restart Sublime
5. Select color scheme from sublime, to select color scheme Goto "Preferences">"Color Scheme">"SublimeDreamweaver-master">"SublimeDreamweaver-master">"Dreamviwer"
6. Restart Again your sublime
7. Now open your file to see effect
8. Thanks
```

**Change Font like dreamviwer after apply color scheme of dreamviwer.**

```
1. Goto "Preferences">"Setting - User"
2. Add this line is your setting json, "font_face":"courier new"
3. Save enjoy
```

[image]

Thanks