# Apply different scopes to the same character in a Sublime Text syntax definition file

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, knitr

I'm trying to create a new `.tmLanguage` file for Sublime Text 2 that defines special fenced code blocks for [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/) and Markdown. These blocks take this form:

````
```{r example_chunk, echo=true}
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)
plot(y ~ x, pch=20)
```
````

There are two sections: (1) the parameters (`{r ...}`) and (2) the actual embedded code (between the closing `}` and the ``` at the end). There are four scopes that need to be applied to delineate the two sections:

- `punctuation.definition.parameters.begin.knitr`
- `punctuation.definition.parameters.end.knitr`
- `punctuation.section.embedded.begin.knitr`
- `punctuation.section.embedded.end.knitr`

Using regular expressions to peg these scopes to parts of code is easy enough (partial code available [here](https://gist.github.com/6302774)). However, two of these scopes need to be applied to the same single character: the final `}` in the parameters section, which ends the parameters and signifies the beginning of the fenced/embedded code.

[image]

However, it appears to be impossible to assign two scopes to the same character in a .tmLanguage file. It's not possible to end the parameters section and begin the embedded section. The first scope defined takes precedence, thus breaking the syntax highlighting.

Is there a way to use a `.tmLanguage` syntax definition to apply two different scopes to the same character in Sublime Text? If not, is there some way I can peg `punctuation.definition.parameters.end.knitr` and `punctuation.section.embedded.begin.knitr` to two different somethings instead of the single `{`? (Keeping in mind that I can't add additional characters to the code block.)

Comment: My [answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12050929/sublime-text-2-change-tags-color/15467203#15467203) got upvoted the other day, posting it here in case it helps. You essentially need to write a JSON file vs editing the `tmLanguage`

Comment: The same thing happens when writing as JSON. I'm using the [AAAPackageDev](https://github.com/SublimeText/AAAPackageDev) package to convert between the two. It's the fact that it's (apparently) impossible to assign two punctuation definitions to the same character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it appears that it's impossible to use two punctuation definitions on the same character (unless there's some way to use some crazy system of nesting to get it to work).

But I fortunately figured out a workaround: a scope can be assigned to a `\n`. So I can use the following regexes to simulate the overlapping scopes:

- `(\})` will capture the closing brace, which can be used as `punctuation.section.embedded.begin.knitr`
- `(?<=\})(.*)(\n)` will capture the `\n` following a closing brace as the second found group, allowing me to assign it to `punctuation.section.embedded.begin.knitr`

Tricky, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way I've found out. Example code in JSON:

```
{
  "match": "((\w+))",
  "captures": {
    "1": {"name": "scope.one"},
    "2": {"name": "scope.two"}
  }
}
```

Should work to my knowledge.

On the other hand you can do a better job by ending the first scope with
`"match": "(?=(?:\}))"` or just live with the ST3 language spec. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- match: '((what you want to match))'
  captures:
    1: first.scope.name
    2: second.scope.name
```